# JavaScript edit links

Tags: javascript

My internal search engine returns search results which look like this:

http://test.mobilkul.se/search/search.html

Right now this JavaScript adds for example `"target=blank"` and `#search="query_String"` to each link at the search results.

I am trying to edit the JavaScript so that every link will be changed from

"http://test.mobilkul.se/search/click?query..."

to

"http://test.mobilkul.se/search/fetch?query..."

I have tried to add:

`.replace('search/click?query=','search/fetch?query=');`

to different places in the JavaScript, but nothing happens..

Can anyone please help?

EDIT:

I have put up a JSfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/shibaja/kK2PZ/

The JavaScript is at the bottom of the html code.

I want to execute these commands on each link:

.replace('&url=%2Fsearch','&urlx=%2Fsearch')

.replace('search/click?query=','search/fetch?query=')

.replace('&title=file','&url=file')

.replace('&spaceId=','&space=')

But I dont know where to put them in the javascript.. Please save my day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('a[href*=query]').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('query', 'fetch'));
});
```

You can tweak to replace the more specific string (`search/click?query`).

Also, remember that `replace` will not affect the original string, but will return you a new one in the way you want.

Hope it helps.

---

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V8B8N/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am really novice with javascript. Could you please tell me where I should put that string in my current javascript code, to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I tried but didnt get it to work. I've put up a JSFiddle. I would really appreciate it if you could help edit that JSFiddle. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Many thanks!!!! I got it to work now. I had forgot to include jquery. Thanks again, you saved my day! Out of curiousity: would it be possible to get the same results without jquery and a window.onload=function() ?

Comment: probably yes, but, is a lot more code, caveats with browsers and etc. jQuery is awesome. You can also use jQuery plugins in your app. Take a look, there is a lot of them out there.